# How do I order an array of data from a Parse, based on a number column

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

On my website, I call my parse database and it gets data from a class and puts it into an array.

Up until a few days ago, it ordered the data what I assume was by the 'createdAt' timestamp. But now it seems to be shifting a few columns up/down randomly in the array, and I don't know why.

I have another column in the class titled 'num', which is just for numbering each row.

Currently, the code that calls the database to get the data looks like this:

```
// Query the content class for rows where the image exists
var content = Parse.Object.extend("content");
var query = new Parse.Query(content);
query.exists("image");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's

    var grid = $("#grid"), slider = $("#slider"), mainContent = $("#main_content"), initialImages, moreImages, totalLoadedImg = 0, remainingImages = results.length;
```

...

Is there a way that when the database is called, it stores the data in the array in the order based on the column 'num' in my database?

Here is a link to the website: http://colorperday.com

Every color has its own column, which also has it's own number, "num". What I am trying to do is order the colors from highest "num" (at the top) to lowest "num" (at the bottom).

Thanks to anyone who is able to help out!

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript but sql. You need to define the order of the returned data within your sql statement i.e. SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY num;

Comment: Parse.com doesn't use SQL, it uses MongoDB.  To interact with it, you use their JavaScript library (as seen with the query in the question's code block).

Comment: @jeff The answer from Daniel worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Parse.com JavaScript Guide](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-constraints):

```
// Sorts the results in ascending order by the score field
query.ascending("score");

// Sorts the results in descending order by the score field
query.descending("score");
```

In your case, replace 'score' with 'num'

Comment: Thank you so much.  All I had to do is literally add this line and it fixed it!

Comment: What about displaying query data in random order?